# How to plot wind direction with lat lon and arrow in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame with `Lat` `Lon` `mean_wind` and `wind_dir`  in each grid cells.
I am trying to make a spatial plot with mean wind in background and wind direction as arrow on each grid cells.

I have tried following on sample data-frame `wind.dt`

```
win.plt<- ggplot(wind.dt,aes(x=Lon,y=Lat))+
           #Mean wind plot : OK
        geom_tile(aes(fill=mean_wind),alpha=1)+
        geom_tile(aes(color=mean_wind), fill=NA) +
        scale_fill_gradientn(colours=(brewer.pal(9,rev("RdYlGn"))))+ 
        scale_color_gradientn(colours=(brewer.pal(9,rev("RdYlGn"))),guide=F)
          #Wind Direction : doesnot work
        geom_segment(arrow = arrow(),aes(yend = Lon + wind_dir, xend = Lat + wind_dir))

win.plt

wind.dt<-structure(list(Lon = c(170.25, 171, 171.75, 172.5, 173.25, 174, 
174.75, 175.5, 176.25, 177, 177.75, 178.5, 179.25, 180, 180.75, 
181.5, 182.25, 183, 183.75, 184.5, 185.25, 186, 186.75, 187.5, 
188.25, 189, 189.75, 190.5, 191.25, 192, 192.75, 193.5, 194.25, 
170.25, 171, 171.75, 172.5, 173.25, 174, 174.75, 175.5, 176.25, 
177, 177.75, 178.5, 179.25, 180, 180.75, 181.5, 182.25, 183, 
183.75, 184.5, 185.25, 186, 186.75, 187.5, 188.25, 189, 189.75, 
190.5, 191.25, 192, 192.75, 193.5, 194.25, 170.25, 171, 171.75, 
172.5, 173.25, 174, 174.75, 175.5, 176.25, 177, 177.75, 178.5, 
179.25, 180, 180.75, 181.5, 182.25, 183, 183.75, 184.5, 185.25, 
186, 186.75, 187.5, 188.25, 189, 189.75, 190.5, 191.25, 192, 
192.75, 193.5, 194.25, 170.25, 171, 171.75, 172.5, 173.25, 174, 
174.75, 175.5, 176.25, 177, 177.75, 178.5, 179.25, 180, 180.75, 
181.5, 182.25, 183, 183.75, 184.5, 185.25, 186, 186.75, 187.5, 
188.25, 189, 189.75, 190.5, 191.25, 192, 192.75, 193.5, 194.25, 
170.25, 171, 171.75, 172.5, 173.25, 174, 174.75, 175.5, 176.25, 
177, 177.75, 178.5, 179.25, 180, 180.75, 181.5, 182.25, 183, 
183.75, 184.5, 185.25, 186, 186.75, 187.5, 188.25, 189, 189.75, 
190.5, 191.25, 192, 192.75, 193.5, 194.25, 170.25, 171, 171.75, 
172.5, 173.25, 174, 174.75, 175.5, 176.25, 177, 177.75, 178.5, 
179.25, 180, 180.75, 181.5, 182.25, 183, 183.75, 184.5, 185.25, 
186, 186.75, 187.5, 188.25, 189, 189.75, 190.5, 191.25, 192, 
192.75, 193.5, 194.25), Lat = c(14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 
14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 
14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 
14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 
14.25, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 
13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 
13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 
13.5, 13.5, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 
12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 
12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 
12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11.25, 
11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 
11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 
11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 
11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5), mean_wind = c(8.34, 8.33, 
8.31, 8.29, 8.27, 8.24, 8.22, 8.2, 8.19, 8.16, 8.14, 8.13, 8.1, 
8.08, 8.06, 8.02, 7.99, 7.96, 7.93, 7.89, 7.85, 7.81, 7.78, 7.73, 
7.7, 7.67, 7.63, 7.62, 7.6, 7.58, 7.56, 7.53, 7.54, 8.65, 8.64, 
8.61, 8.59, 8.56, 8.53, 8.51, 8.48, 8.46, 8.43, 8.41, 8.39, 8.38, 
8.37, 8.33, 8.31, 8.28, 8.24, 8.2, 8.15, 8.12, 8.07, 8.03, 8.01, 
7.97, 7.94, 7.92, 7.89, 7.87, 7.85, 7.85, 7.83, 7.8, 8.85, 8.84, 
8.81, 8.8, 8.77, 8.74, 8.72, 8.69, 8.67, 8.65, 8.63, 8.61, 8.59, 
8.58, 8.55, 8.54, 8.5, 8.46, 8.44, 8.4, 8.37, 8.33, 8.29, 8.26, 
8.21, 8.18, 8.16, 8.13, 8.12, 8.09, 8.06, 8.06, 8.03, 9.01, 8.99, 
8.96, 8.94, 8.91, 8.89, 8.86, 8.83, 8.82, 8.79, 8.78, 8.77, 8.75, 
8.75, 8.73, 8.7, 8.68, 8.66, 8.63, 8.59, 8.55, 8.52, 8.47, 8.43, 
8.4, 8.38, 8.35, 8.32, 8.31, 8.29, 8.26, 8.25, 8.23, 9.07, 9.06, 
9.04, 9.01, 8.99, 8.97, 8.94, 8.92, 8.91, 8.9, 8.89, 8.88, 8.88, 
8.87, 8.86, 8.84, 8.83, 8.8, 8.75, 8.74, 8.7, 8.67, 8.63, 8.59, 
8.57, 8.53, 8.52, 8.51, 8.47, 8.47, 8.45, 8.42, 8.41, 9.1, 9.08, 
9.06, 9.04, 9.02, 9, 8.98, 8.97, 8.96, 8.96, 8.95, 8.95, 8.97, 
8.96, 8.96, 8.94, 8.91, 8.89, 8.86, 8.84, 8.8, 8.76, 8.73, 8.69, 
8.67, 8.64, 8.63, 8.63, 8.61, 8.59, 8.57, 8.54, 8.53), wind_dir = c(81.27, 
81.34, 81.38, 81.44, 81.47, 81.34, 81.31, 81.51, 81.56, 81.46, 
81.54, 81.53, 81.42, 81.53, 81.66, 81.76, 81.86, 81.96, 82.02, 
82.28, 82.65, 82.77, 83.07, 83.46, 83.78, 84.15, 84.52, 84.92, 
85.39, 85.87, 86.15, 86.38, 86.53, 81.34, 81.34, 81.38, 81.31, 
81.2, 81.25, 81.39, 81.36, 81.31, 81.4, 81.47, 81.48, 81.59, 
81.64, 81.58, 81.62, 81.75, 81.98, 82.13, 82.26, 82.52, 82.77, 
82.97, 83.15, 83.49, 83.74, 84.23, 84.78, 85.04, 85.49, 85.73, 
86.05, 86.35, 81.5, 81.41, 81.32, 81.28, 81.32, 81.31, 81.24, 
81.17, 81.28, 81.33, 81.24, 81.3, 81.44, 81.46, 81.55, 81.76, 
81.8, 81.88, 82.11, 82.31, 82.4, 82.61, 82.88, 82.95, 83.29, 
83.59, 83.93, 84.46, 84.8, 85.26, 85.47, 85.78, 86.11, 81.3, 
81.29, 81.29, 81.28, 81.32, 81.22, 81.24, 81.32, 81.31, 81.23, 
81.34, 81.47, 81.37, 81.42, 81.5, 81.6, 81.78, 81.98, 82.06, 
82.26, 82.49, 82.52, 82.7, 82.79, 83.05, 83.46, 83.79, 84.18, 
84.5, 84.91, 85.23, 85.49, 85.7, 81.31, 81.33, 81.28, 81.19, 
81.26, 81.29, 81.36, 81.24, 81.16, 81.18, 81.23, 81.23, 81.23, 
81.47, 81.5, 81.55, 81.73, 81.99, 82.14, 82.18, 82.41, 82.46, 
82.63, 82.83, 82.97, 83.27, 83.62, 84.01, 84.34, 84.64, 85.01, 
85.38, 85.55, 81.14, 81.14, 81.1, 81.15, 81.2, 81.1, 81.14, 81.06, 
81.21, 81.26, 81.13, 81.16, 81.17, 81.22, 81.28, 81.63, 81.71, 
81.77, 82.13, 82.22, 82.37, 82.48, 82.56, 82.7, 82.92, 83.19, 
83.43, 83.74, 84.15, 84.59, 84.89, 85.22, 85.39)), row.names = c(NA, 
-198L), .Names = c("Lon", "Lat", "mean_wind", "wind_dir"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`geom_spoke` was made for this particular sort of plot. Cleaned up a little,

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(wind.dt, 
       aes(x = Lon , 
           y = Lat, 
           fill = mean_wind, 
           angle = wind_dir, 
           radius = scales::rescale(mean_wind, c(.2, .8)))) +
    geom_raster() +
    geom_spoke(arrow = arrow(length = unit(.05, 'inches'))) + 
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") + 
    coord_equal(expand = 0) + 
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
          legend.direction = 'horizontal')
```

[image]

Adjust scaling and sizes as desired.

---

## Edit: Controlling the number of arrows

To adjust the number of arrows, a quick-and-dirty route is to subset one of the aesthetics passed to `geom_spoke` with a recycling vector that will cause some rows to be dropped, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(wind.dt, 
       aes(x = Lon , 
           y = Lat, 
           fill = mean_wind, 
           angle = wind_dir[c(TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA)],    # causes some values not to plot
           radius = scales::rescale(mean_wind, c(.2, .8)))) +
    geom_raster() +
    geom_spoke(arrow = arrow(length = unit(.05, 'inches'))) + 
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") + 
    coord_equal(expand = 0) + 
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
          legend.direction = 'horizontal')
#> Warning: Removed 158 rows containing missing values (geom_spoke).
```

[image]

This depends on your data frame being in order and is not infinitely flexible, but if it gets you a nice plot with minimal effort, can be useless nonetheless.

A more robust approach is to make a subsetted data frame for use by `geom_spoke`, say, selecting every other value of `Lon` and `Lat`, here using recycling subsetting on a vector of distinct values:

```r
library(dplyr)

wind.arrows <- wind.dt %>% 
    filter(Lon %in% sort(unique(Lon))[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
           Lat %in% sort(unique(Lat))[c(TRUE, FALSE)])

ggplot(wind.dt, 
       aes(x = Lon , 
           y = Lat, 
           fill = mean_wind, 
           angle = wind_dir, 
           radius = scales::rescale(mean_wind, c(.2, .8)))) +
    geom_raster() +
    geom_spoke(data = wind.arrows,    # this is the only difference in the plotting code
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(.05, 'inches'))) + 
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") + 
    coord_equal(expand = 0) + 
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
          legend.direction = 'horizontal')
```

[image]

This approach makes getting (and scaling) a grid fairly easy, but getting a diamond pattern will take a bit more logic:

```r
wind.arrows <- wind.dt %>% 
    filter(( Lon %in% sort(unique(Lon))[c(TRUE, FALSE)] & 
             Lat %in% sort(unique(Lat))[c(TRUE, FALSE)] ) | 
           ( Lon %in% sort(unique(Lon))[c(FALSE, TRUE)] & 
             Lat %in% sort(unique(Lat))[c(FALSE, TRUE)] ))
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thank you. In addition, how can I plot arrows by skipping every 5 grids? ie plot arrow on the first grid cell and 5 th and 10th and so on.

Comment: @LilyNature Updated with a couple options

Comment: it seems the direction were not plotted properly here, for example first gird cell has value of 81.7 degree. The arrow doesn't seems show 81.7 degree. what should be changed to make it proper direction.

Comment: Oops, the docs don't state it explicitly, but looking at the example, it looks like the angles are supposed to be in radians, not degrees, so set `angle = wind_dir / 180 * pi` in `aes` or convert beforehand and everything will point more or less upwards (angles are measured from the positive x-axis).

Comment: Thank you @ alistaire, to get proper direction ( with reference to meteorological convention) we have to subtract the direction from 270 and use angle = wind_dir / 180 * pi.