# How to get a legend on geom_spoke

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have wind speed and direction. I want to get the wind speed in legend based on the length of the arrow and line (define by radius in following code).Based on  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880918/how-to-plot-wind-direction-with-lat-lon-and-arrow-in-ggplot2/47881159#47881159) question, how can i add the speed in legend with the arrow.

```
   library(ggplot2)
        wind.dt<-structure(list(Lon = c(170.25, 171, 171.75, 172.5, 173.25, 174, 
174.75, 175.5, 176.25, 177, 177.75, 178.5, 179.25, 180, 180.75, 
181.5, 182.25, 183, 183.75, 184.5, 185.25, 186, 186.75, 187.5, 
188.25, 189, 189.75, 190.5, 191.25, 192), Lat = c(14.25, 14.25, 
14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 
14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 
14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 
14.25), mean_wind = c(8.34, 8.33, 8.31, 8.29, 8.27, 8.24, 8.22, 
8.2, 8.19, 8.16, 8.14, 8.13, 8.1, 8.08, 8.06, 8.02, 7.99, 7.96, 
7.93, 7.89, 7.85, 7.81, 7.78, 7.73, 7.7, 7.67, 7.63, 7.62, 7.6, 
7.58), wind_dir = c(81.27, 81.34, 81.38, 81.44, 81.47, 81.34, 
81.31, 81.51, 81.56, 81.46, 81.54, 81.53, 81.42, 81.53, 81.66, 
81.76, 81.86, 81.96, 82.02, 82.28, 82.65, 82.77, 83.07, 83.46, 
83.78, 84.15, 84.52, 84.92, 85.39, 85.87)), .Names = c("Lon", 
"Lat", "mean_wind", "wind_dir"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
ggplot(wind.dt, 
       aes(x = Lon , 
           y = Lat, 
           fill = mean_wind, 
           angle = wind_dir, 
           radius = scales::rescale(mean_wind, c(.2, .8)))) +
    geom_raster() +
    geom_spoke(arrow = arrow(length = unit(.05, 'inches'))) + 
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") + 
    coord_equal(expand = 0) + 
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
          legend.direction = 'horizontal')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat coarse way of doing it, modeled after the mechanism used in [the `scatterpie` package](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/scatterpie). It's a function that generates a list of `geoms` to add to the plot. The biggest caveat is that you can only place the legend inside the plot panel.

```
library(scales)

geom_spoke_legend <- function(r, x, y, n = 5, scaled = c(0.2,0.8), 
                              arrow = NULL, label = NULL) {

  dd <- data.frame(breaks = pretty_breaks(n)(r))
  dd$radius <- rescale(dd$breaks, to = scaled, from = range(r, na.rm = T, finite = T))
  dd$xpos <- seq(0, by = round(max(scaled)), length.out = length(dd$breaks))
  dd$xpos <- dd$xpos + x
  dd$ypos <- rep(y, length(dd$breaks))



  g <- list(
    geom_spoke(data = dd,
               aes(x = xpos, y = ypos + 0.5, radius = radius),
               angle = pi/4, arrow = arrow,
               inherit.aes = F),
    geom_text(data = dd,
              aes(x = xpos, y = ypos, label = format(breaks)),
              hjust = 0, vjust = 0, size = 3,
              inherit.aes = F)
  )

  if (!is.null(label)) {
      dd1 <- dd[1,]
      dd1$label <- label

      g <- c(g,
             geom_text(data = dd1,
                       aes(x = xpos, y = ypos-0.5, label = label),
                       hjust = 0, vjust = 0, size = 3,
                       inherit.aes = F))
  }

  g
}
```

To use this function, you have to supply a couple arguments explicitly:

1. The vector of radiuses from the original dataframe
2. The desired x position of the lower left corner of the legend in the panel
3. Same as #2, but for y

And optionally some additional arguments:

4. The number of breaks you want in the legend
5. The rescaled length of the vectors, used in your original plot when you called `rescale`
6. The `arrow()` call from your original `geom_spoke`
7. A title

To use it, you do something like this:

```
ggplot(wind.dt, 
       aes(x = Lon, 
           y = Lat, 
           fill = mean_wind)) +
  geom_raster() +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = wind_dir, 
                 radius = scales::rescale(mean_wind, c(.2, .8))),
             arrow = arrow(length = unit(.05, 'inches'))) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") + 
  coord_equal(expand = 0) + 
  theme_classic() +                       # added for legibility
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
        legend.direction = 'horizontal') +
  # use the function like any other geom*
  geom_spoke_legend(wind.dt$mean_wind, x = 186, y = 15.5, 
                    arrow = arrow(length = unit(.05, 'inches')),
                    label = "Mean windspeed")
```

[image]

This solution isn't optimized for faceted plots, and right now you'd need to hardcode in some details if you wanted to customize them.

As a side note, the "right" way to do it would be to draw arbitrary grobs, which is the way that the internal `ggplot::draw_key*` functions work. However, there's no way to keep the length of the x and y coordinates the same as in the plot panel, so that's why I used the solution from the `scatterpie` package.