# Is it possible to rasterize a ggplot in such way that the resulting raster object represents the ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

Is it possible to rasterize a ggplot in such way that the resulting raster object represents the ggplot?

I have a following ggplot p:

[image]

If I convert it to a raster object and plot it again it looks like this:

[image]

This is how I create and rasterize the plot p:

```
library(ratser)
library(ggplot)

p<-ggplot(wind_data, aes(x = lon, y = lat)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = lon + 0.1, yend = lat + 0.1),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm")), size = 0.25)   

p<-p +theme_void() + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(3.604383, 14.60482), ylim = c(47.07157 ,54.73807 )) + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black") )



ggsave(plot=p, "my_ggplot.tiff", device = "tiff")
raster <- raster::raster("my_ggplot.tiff") # OR stack("my_ggplot.tiff") for colored images
lat_long <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]][c("x.range","y.range")]

extent(raster) <- c(lat_long$x.range,lat_long$y.range)
projection(raster) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

**Here is wind_data data.frame:**

```
      wind_data<-structure(list(lon = c(8.87312091729266, 8.71871388830953, 10.5679127453358, 
10.7216122406487, 10.4141464047873, 10.5679127453358, 10.1064188710028, 
11.3357135330171, 11.4890576651767, 11.1822955254471), lat = c(54.6482360923283, 
54.5584019137964, 54.2888913181823, 54.2888913181823, 54.1990517614177, 
54.1990517614177, 54.0193686018903, 53.6599860593553, 53.6599860593553, 
53.5701370357575), dd = c(241, 238, 247, 240, 240, 246, 247, 
246, 245, 247)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

**Here is the data of the plot p:**

```
        p<-structure(list(data = structure(list(lon = c(8.87312091729266, 
8.71871388830953, 10.5679127453358, 10.7216122406487, 10.4141464047873, 
10.5679127453358, 10.1064188710028, 11.3357135330171, 11.4890576651767, 
11.1822955254471), lat = c(54.6482360923283, 54.5584019137964, 
54.2888913181823, 54.2888913181823, 54.1990517614177, 54.1990517614177, 
54.0193686018903, 53.6599860593553, 53.6599860593553, 53.5701370357575
), dd = c(241, 238, 247, 240, 240, 246, 247, 246, 245, 247)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), layers = list(<environment>), scales = <environment>, 
    mapping = structure(list(x = ~lon, y = ~lat), class = "uneval"), 
    theme = structure(list(line = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
    "element")), rect = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
    "element")), text = structure(list(family = "", face = "plain", 
        colour = "black", size = 11, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, 
        angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), title = NULL, aspect.ratio = NULL, axis.title = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
    "element")), axis.title.x = NULL, axis.title.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.title.x.bottom = NULL, axis.title.y = NULL, axis.title.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.title.y.right = NULL, axis.text = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), axis.text.x = NULL, axis.text.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.text.x.bottom = NULL, axis.text.y = NULL, axis.text.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.text.y.right = NULL, axis.ticks = NULL, axis.ticks.x = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.x.top = NULL, axis.ticks.x.bottom = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.y = NULL, axis.ticks.y.left = NULL, axis.ticks.y.right = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length = structure(0, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), axis.ticks.length.x = NULL, axis.ticks.length.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length.x.bottom = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length.y.left = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y.right = NULL, 
        axis.line = structure(list(colour = "black", size = NULL, 
            linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), axis.line.x = NULL, axis.line.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.line.x.bottom = NULL, axis.line.y = NULL, axis.line.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.line.y.right = NULL, legend.background = NULL, legend.margin = NULL, 
        legend.spacing = NULL, legend.spacing.x = NULL, legend.spacing.y = NULL, 
        legend.key = NULL, legend.key.size = structure(1.2, unit = 3L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.key.height = NULL, legend.key.width = NULL, 
        legend.text = structure(list(family = NULL, face = NULL, 
            colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.text.align = NULL, legend.title = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.title.align = NULL, legend.position = "right", 
        legend.direction = NULL, legend.justification = NULL, 
        legend.box = NULL, legend.box.just = NULL, legend.box.margin = NULL, 
        legend.box.background = NULL, legend.box.spacing = NULL, 
        panel.background = NULL, panel.border = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.spacing = structure(5.5, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), panel.spacing.x = NULL, panel.spacing.y = NULL, 
        panel.grid = NULL, panel.grid.major = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.grid.minor = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.grid.major.x = NULL, panel.grid.major.y = NULL, 
        panel.grid.minor.x = NULL, panel.grid.minor.y = NULL, 
        panel.ontop = FALSE, plot.background = NULL, plot.title = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(5.5, 0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.title.position = "panel", plot.subtitle = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(5.5, 0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(5.5, 0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption.position = "panel", plot.tag = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.tag.position = "topleft", plot.margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), unit = 3L, class = c("simpleUnit", "unit", 
        "unit_v2")), strip.background = NULL, strip.background.x = NULL, 
        strip.background.y = NULL, strip.placement = NULL, strip.text = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.text.x = NULL, strip.text.y = NULL, 
        strip.switch.pad.grid = structure(2.75, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.switch.pad.wrap = structure(2.75, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2"))), class = c("theme", "gg"), complete = TRUE, validate = TRUE), 
    coordinates = <environment>, facet = <environment>, plot_env = <environment>, 
    labels = list(x = "lon", y = "lat", xend = "lon + 0.1", yend = "lat + 0.1")), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot"))
```

If i understand it correctly the resulting raster object should have only min value 0 and max value 1 and represent the arrows in lat long coordinates.
But it does not look like this.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, you must share `wind_data`, the plot p is not reproducible since it have some <environment> in it (last three lines).

Comment: Oh im sorry. I added the data.

Comment: Uhm, why would you use spatial wind data to create a plot, just in order to export the image to disk and re-import as a raster object? This whole workflow seems flawed since you're losing a lot of information. Why not simply perform some vector to raster conversion and preserve all the spatial information? However, what exactly is your goal in the end?

Comment: @falk-env thank you for taking your time. In the end of the whole chain i actually would like to draw those arrows with gejson on a map. I can convert a raster to gejson easily so thats why I chose this route. I was not able to draw an arrow in a raster at coorinate (lon,lat) with a degree x.. so I went the way over ggplot. Here i can I daw arrows over the area described by xmin xmax ymin ymax and an arrow described by lat long and a degree 0..360

Comment: I assume you're not targeting a printed map and also not working with ArcMap/QGIS, but rather working with a JS framework like Leaflet/OpenLayers if your target is GeoJSON in the end? What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880918/how-to-plot-wind-direction-with-lat-lon-and-arrow-in-ggplot2) or [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175398/interactive-and-dynamic-map-with-wind-data-in-r-leaflet) solution?

Comment: No its an iOS SDK. The first link you suggested is basically what im doing and was using it for inspiration to plot the "wind map".

Comment: Ok, and I assume `sf::st_as_sf(wind_data, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "epsg:4326") |> sf::st_write("wind_data.geojson")` does not suit your needs?

Comment: @falk-env thank you again for taking your time to discuss this with me! This approach would only produce a gps point on a map if i understand it correctly. I would need an arrow that represents the direction based on the dd value.

Comment: hmm I could create another point by using the starting point and the degree (dd) value ... and then use your suggestion to connect those dots.. but it still would be no arrow, just a line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249055/discussion-between-falk-env-and-andreas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure about this conversion on a meta level, but technically you should be able to solve it this way:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.33
library(geodata)

# write your plot to disk
ggsave(plot = p, "my_ggplot.jpeg")

# import as SpatRaster object
r <- rast("my_ggplot.jpeg")
#> Warning: [rast] unknown extent

# your object has 3 layers with values ranging from 0 to 255
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1668, 3609, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 3609, 0, 1668  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> source      : my_ggplot.jpeg 
#> colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
#> names       : my_ggplot_1, my_ggplot_2, my_ggplot_3

summary(r)
#> Warning: [summary] used a sample
#>   my_ggplot_1   my_ggplot_2   my_ggplot_3 
#>  Min.   : 62   Min.   : 62   Min.   : 62  
#>  1st Qu.:255   1st Qu.:255   1st Qu.:255  
#>  Median :255   Median :255   Median :255  
#>  Mean   :254   Mean   :254   Mean   :254  
#>  3rd Qu.:255   3rd Qu.:255   3rd Qu.:255  
#>  Max.   :255   Max.   :255   Max.   :255

# provide proper georeferencing information by crs and extent definition
crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs"
ext(r) <- c(3.604383, 14.60482, 47.07157, 54.73807) |> ext()
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1668, 3609, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.003048057, 0.004596223  (x, y)
#> extent      : 3.604383, 14.60482, 47.07157, 54.73807  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source      : my_ggplot.jpeg 
#> colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
#> names       : my_ggplot_1, my_ggplot_2, my_ggplot_3

# this is optional, just to verify the correct position
adm <- geodata::gadm("de", path = tempdir())

# inspect result
plot(r)
plot(adm, add = TRUE, border = "red")
```

[image]